# $\omega$-limit set in $\mathbb S^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $X(x,y,z)=(-y+xz^2,x+yz^2,-zx^2-zy^2)$ be a vectorial field in $\mathbb S^2$, computationally it is easy to see that the $\omega-$limit set of any point other than the poles is the equator, but I don't know how to prove this mathematically, any ideas please?
[image]

Comment: How do you normally find $\omega$ limit sets?

Comment: @User203940 Until now I have been working with fields in the plane where it was simpler, and when I faced a field in the sphere I used spherical coordinates but said field was very basic (whose orbits were the meridians).

Answer (score 3):

The poles are clearly fixed points. Consider any other point. To show that its omega limit set is equal to the equator, we calculate things explicitly.

First, let us verify that the omega limit set must be contained in the equator.
Since $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ on the sphere, the $z$-direction of the vector field is $X_3(x,y,z) = -z(1-z^2)$.
Thus, the orbit $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ satisfies $z'(t) = -z(t)(1-z(t)^2)$.
The solution to this ODE with initial value $z_0 \in (-1,1)$ is
$$
z(t) = \mathrm{sign}(z_0) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ce^{2t}}}
$$
with $c = z_0^{-2}-1$.
Since $c > 0$, we see from this that $z(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.
This shows that the orbit approaches the equator and, hence, the omega limit set must be a subset of the equator.

Second, we show that the omega limit set equals the whole equator.
This can be seen easiest in cylindrical coordinates.
In these, the vector field $X$ is expressed as
$$
X(r,\theta,z) =
\begin{pmatrix}
rz^2\\
-1\\
-zr^2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In particular, $\theta(t) = \theta(0)-t$ (mod $2\pi$), meaning that the orbit rotates counterclockwise around the equator with speed 1.

Comment: Wow what a great answer, thank you very much for taking the time to detail things. I only have one query regarding $\theta'$, when I do the calculations I get the following: $\theta'=\frac{y'x-yx'}{r^2}=1$, I don't get $\theta'(t)=-r(t)$. Maybe my operations are wrong but could you take a look please?

Comment: I can't tell how you got to your result and where the mistake might be, but I can tell you how I derived it. The transformation for cylindrical coordinates is $h(r,\theta,z) = (r\sin \theta,r\cos \theta,z)$. The transformed vector field is $X(r,\theta,z) = (dh)^{-1}_{(r,\theta,z)} (X(h(r,\theta,z)))$. The matrix $(dh)^{-1}_{(r,\theta,z)}$ is $$(dh)^{-1}_{(r,\theta,z)}=\begin{pmatrix} \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$X(h(r,\theta,z))=\begin{pmatrix} -r\cos\theta+rz^2\sin\theta \\ r\sin\theta+rz^2\cos\theta \\ -zr^2 \end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: Whit your method I think that $dh(r,\theta,z)=\begin{pmatrix} \sin\theta & r\cos\theta & 0\\ \cos\theta &-r\sin\theta & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $(dh)^{-1}_{(r,\theta,z)}=\begin{pmatrix} \sin\theta &\cos\theta & 0 \\ \frac{\cos\theta}{r} &-\frac{\sin\theta}{r} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ in this case $X(r,\theta,z)=(dh)^{-1}_{(r,\theta,z)}(X(h(r,\theta,z)))=\begin{pmatrix} rz^2\\-1\\-zr^2\end{pmatrix}$. On the other hand, $x=r\sin\theta$ and $y=r\cos\theta$ then $\theta=\arctan(x/y)$ $$\theta'=\frac{(x/y)'}{1+(x/y)^2}=\frac{x'y-xy'}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{(-y+xz^2)y-x(x+yz^2)}{x^2+y^2}=-1$$

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I forgot the '$r$'. I update the answer now.